# How to change the format of a KPI in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to see if someone can help me, I installed SSRS and I am generating a KPI to show certain information, everything is going well, the problem is that the thousands format appears with "." instead of ",", could someone help me to give it the correct format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG1px.png)

I have not been able to find a solution, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separator should be controlled by the Windows Region setting. There isn't a setting to change it in SSRS. The only other way I can think of is to create the format in the SQL and pass the value as text, but then you couldn't use any mathematical expressions on the text value.

[image]